# Touchscreen, WebCam and Screenlight not working!

Tags: screen, webcam, touchscreen, camera

I have an Acer Aspire V5 that came with windows 8. Now I have the Ubuntu 12.10, 32 bits.

First, the command to dim or brighten the screen with -Fn up or down- is acting on the screen (it shows that it is dimming or increasing on the bar on the screen), but the screen doesn't do so.

Second, my computer is a touchscreen, still working with Ubuntu, but seems to be buggy a little bit from time to time. For example, it is supposed to be a one-finger scroll up or down. It acts like it on PDF files but not on the Internet. I cannot find anywhere in Ubuntu how to program the settings of the touchscreen. Are there any programs to download to do so, or is touchscreen support not in Ubuntu yet? It also goes nuts (not frequently, but still...) as it closes the tabs or goes to the Ubuntu purple page that shows the crypting things when I start my computer. Then it goes right back to where I was on my page as if nothing had happened.

Last of all, my computer suddenly lost the Web cam when I am using Skype. The in-build cam in the laptop shows me a green light beside the cam but the video is all black. Cannot see anything. This has happened two days ago and cannot understand why since it has been working since I got with Ubuntu.

Those are my concerns. If anyone could help that would be much appreciated.

Peace

Comment: Does ubuntu have touch support? I dont hink so. It could be in beta.

Comment: I don't know. Right now it is working because it acts like a mouse on the screen. But I do not understand what is the Beta you are talking about.

Comment: `Beta` is a pre release version of any software or feature for that purpose. If its is beta version it might not working well or is being tested e.g. Consumer preview of Widows 8 may be called as beta.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. But beside the touchscreen do you think you can help me with the lighting or my newly problem with my cam on skype?

Answer (score 0):

Try the instructions here: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam/Troubleshooting
helped me with my Acer V5, at least with guvcview I know my webcam is supported... hm, but still black in Skype. Good luck!

Comment: yeah I know the cam is alright because i have Cheese application and it works. But there is a problem with when the camera is running with the Internet like skype and google+  hangout thing.. SO that is what I have found out so far. But the weird thing is when I re-install Ubuntu on my laptop the Cam works for a few days on Skype and suddenly goes black for no reason or any updates. I am thinking to go and try Fedora or Open SUSE to see if they have the same problem.